# Program stop when server try to receive client data

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, serversocket

I'm trying to make a simple multiplayer game in Greenfoot for a school project.

If I remove `updatePosition();` in the player script, the server can move and the client gets the data. However, when I try to get the data from the client and call `updatePosition();` in the player script, it stops when the server tries to call `receiveInt()`. The terminal of the server side shows "Works Server" "2" "Works Server" "2" and then the program stops on the client and server.

**"GameManager":**

```
import greenfoot.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyWorld extends World
{
    public Server server;
    public Client client;
    public boolean Server = false;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class MyWorld.
     * 
     */
    public MyWorld()
    {    
        super(600, 400, 1);
        Player player = new Player(this);
        addObject(player, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
    }

    public void act()
    {
        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("q"))
        {
            if(Server)
            {
                server.close();
            }else
            {
                client.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void init()
    {
        Object[] options = {"Server","Client"};
        int i = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Host as server or join as client?", "Selection", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
        if(i == 0)
        {
            server = new Server(this);
            Server = true;

            Player2 player2 = new Player2();
            addObject(player2, 0, 0);
        }else if(i == 1)
        {
            client = new Client(this);
            
            Player2 player2 = new Player2();
            addObject(player2, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public class Server
    {
        MyWorld myWorld;
        public ServerSocket serverSocket;
        public Socket skt;
        private ObjectInputStream inServer;
        private ObjectOutputStream outServer;
        public Server(MyWorld myWorl)
        {
            this.myWorld = myWorl;
            try
            {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
                skt = serverSocket.accept();
                inServer = new ObjectInputStream(skt.getInputStream());
                outServer = new ObjectOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                close();
            }
        }

        public void sendInts(int ...arr) {
            try {
                outServer.writeObject(arr);
                Greenfoot.delay(1);
                outServer.flush();
            }
            catch(NullPointerException ex) {
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {
            }
        }

        public int[] receiveInts() {
            int[] datServer = null;
            try {
                datServer = (int[])inServer.readObject();
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                close();
            }
            catch(NullPointerException ex) {
                close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {
                close();
            }
            return datServer;
        }

        public void close()
        {
            try {
                outServer.close();
                inServer.close();
                skt.close();
                serverSocket.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error closing streams...");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Client
    {
        MyWorld myWorld;
        private ObjectOutputStream outClient;
        private ObjectInputStream inClient;
        public Socket clientSocket;
        public Client(MyWorld myWorl)
        {
            this.myWorld = myWorl;
            try
            {
                clientSocket = new Socket("localhost",8888);
                outClient = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                inClient = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                close();
            }   
        }

        public void sendInts(int ...arr) {
            try {
                outClient.writeObject(arr);
                Greenfoot.delay(1);
                outClient.flush();
            }
            catch(NullPointerException ex) {
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {
            }
        }

        public int[] receiveInts() {
            int[] datClient = null;
            try {
                datClient = (int[])inClient.readObject();
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(NullPointerException ex) {
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {
                close();
            }
            return datClient;
        }

        public void close()
        {
            try {
                outClient.close();
                inClient.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error closing streams...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Player:**

```
import greenfoot.*;

public class Player extends Actor
{
    private MyWorld myWorld;
    private Player2 player2;

    public Player(MyWorld myWorl)
    {
        myWorld = myWorl;
    }

    private boolean startSelectionBool = false;

    public void act() 
    {
        if(!startSelectionBool)
        {
            if(Greenfoot.getMouseInfo() != null)
            {
                if(Greenfoot.mouseClicked(this))
                {
                    myWorld.init();
                    startSelectionBool = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(myWorld.Server == true)
            {
                updateServer();
                //System.out.println("Server");
            }else
            {
                updateClient();
                //System.out.println("Client");
            }
        }
    }   

    public void updateServer()
    {
        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("w"))
        {
            setLocation(this.getX(), this.getY()-1);
        }
        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("s"))
        {
            setLocation(this.getX(), this.getY()+1);
        }
        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("a"))
        {
            setLocation(this.getX()-1, this.getY());
        }
        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("d"))
        {
            setLocation(this.getX()+1, this.getY());
        }
        myWorld.server.sendInts(this.getX(), this.getY());

        updatePosition();
    }

    public void updatePosition()
    {
        int[] w1 = myWorld.server.receiveInts();
        
        if (w1 != null)
        {
            Greenfoot.delay(5);
            player2 = getWorld().getObjects(Player2.class).get(0);

            System.out.println("Works Server");
            player2.setLocation(w1[0], w1[1]);
            System.out.println("2");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("1");
        }
    }

    public void updateClient()
    {
        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("w"))
        {
            setLocation(this.getX(), this.getY()-1);
        }
        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("s"))
        {
            setLocation(this.getX(), this.getY()+1);
        }
        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("a"))
        {
            setLocation(this.getX()-1, this.getY());
        }
        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("d"))
        {
            setLocation(this.getX()+1, this.getY());
        }
        myWorld.client.sendInts(this.getX(), this.getY());

        int[] w2 = myWorld.client.receiveInts();
        
        if (w2 == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Return Client");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            player2 = getWorld().getObjects(Player2.class).get(0);

            player2.setLocation(w2[0], w2[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that looks odd is that in `updatePosition()` you call `receiveInts()` twice, so the first one will read from the socket then discard it, and the second one will have to wait for the next corresponding `sendInts()` call.  I suspect you want the assignment to `w1` before the if statement in `updatePosition()`, then check if `w1` is null.

Comment: Exactly. He is received the ints and then throwing them away, then trying to receive them again but blocking forever because they aren't being sent twice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the script so you can see what I changed. Now the server terminal says: "Works Server" "2" "Works Server" "2" and then stops. But the client and the server both get the position once, change the position of player2 and then it stops.

Comment: Have you also fixed the similar problem in `updateClient()` where you are also calling `receiveInts()` twice?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same as in `updatePosition()`

Comment: I also updated the script here, so you can see the newest version

Comment: I pasted your latest code for MyWorld and Player into a new project (with a new actor named Player2 with the default code), loaded the project twice in Greenfoot on the same machine, and it does not stop.  It prints "Works Server" "2" over and over on the server end.  Maybe there is some other code causing a problem, perhaps in Player2?

Comment: It seems that player 2 caused the problem. I deleted and re-added player 2 and now it works fine...
Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!